# Alert for Error Count on GCP - How to use time range?

Tags: monitoring, google-cloud-monitoring

I have created a policy for alerting me when the app starting to showing errors. I didn´t find a way to setup the time range. Actually I don´t know the range time that the policy is looking for errors.

```
Conditions
Policy violates when ANY condition is met

Configurations
Log query
resource.type = "cloud_run_revision" resource.labels.service_name = "whatsapp-nabla-bridge" resource.labels.location = "us-east1" severity>=ERROR

Notification rate limit
One notification per 15 minutes

Incident autoclose duration
7 days
```